# using python pandas lookup another dataframe and return corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes;

`df1` as;

```
Name      Role
Jim       Accounts
Sam       Purchase
Rhea      Sales
```

`df2` as;

```
Name     Date
Jim      1/1/2000
Jim      2/1/2000
Jim      3/1/2000
Sam      1/1/2000
Sam      2/1/2000
Rhea     1/1/2000
Rhea     2/1/2000
```

I want to lookup `df1` and have the output as;

```
    Name     Date          Role
    Jim      1/1/2000      Accounts
    Jim      2/1/2000      Accounts
    Jim      3/1/2000      Accounts
    Sam      1/1/2000      Purchase
    Sam      2/1/2000      Purchase
    Rhea     1/1/2000      Sales
    Rhea     2/1/2000      Sales
```

I'm unable to figure out Pandas' lookup feature.

Comment: You don't seem to have the right terminology, in pandas you are looking for either [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge) or [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pandas.DataFrame.join).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function:

```
df2.merge(df1)
```